# show image from cache browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image

```
  var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  $("#capLogin").attr("src", "Image/Captcha/CaptchaControl.aspx?id="+timestamp);
```

or

```
  $("#capLogin").attr("src", "Image/Captcha/CaptchaControl.aspx?id="+Math.random());
```

But it still shows duplicate image in the successive application

Comment: Probably the page itself is cached, you need to prevent it using server side code.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent your page from being cached on the browser, try adding these lines to the `header`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent cache try adding this to the `Page_Load` of `CaptchaControl.aspx` code:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

This will send proper headers to the browser asking it to not cache the contents.